# When using Phonegap, can we deploy our sqlite db with the application and access it from within the application?

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, cordova

I am building out an app that will be used primarily by BB OS5. I am considering Phonegap, and I wanted to find out if we can deploy our sqlite db with the application and access it from within the application?

If so, is there a size limit on the database? and how is the performance?

Comment: It supports BlackBerry WebWorks (OS 6.0 and higher) http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html

Comment: Thanks, Ray. I wish I could vote your comment up.

Answer (score 0):

[PhoneGap Database API](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html) requires BlackBerry WebWorks (OS 6.0 and higher)

But I would also like to point you to a toolkit that you may find useful in building a database backed webapp.
[Supporting Gears using HTML5 in BlackBerry WebWorks applications](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Supporting-Gears-using-HTML5-in-BlackBerry-WebWorks-applications/ta-p/557280)

The JavaScript® toolkit provides the following HTML5 interfaces as a simple layer on top of the Gears API’s currently available in BlackBerry Device Software 5.0:

- Geolocation
- Timer
- Database
- Worker
- XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

@Ray Vahey, phonegap support OS 5.0+ not complete but in part...

You can use Phonegap + gears in your app in order to use storage on OS 5, for OS 6+ you can use the Phonegap API: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Comment: Thanks, I really meant the database api is not officially supported by PhoneGap on BlackBerry OS's older than 6 but I see I didn't make that clear.